# Filter Process script Library

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a form called *Approver* in "Approver" db.

The form has two editable text fields: **Office** and  **Group**. It also has a dialog list field **superior1**.

The **superior1** dialog list field should show the staff details filtered based on office & group:

if `office = TSP & group = HR` from the approver form, then shud filter the staffs based on these fields group" & "office" with the "Staff info" view of another database "TSP_Staff" and show in **superior1**.

But it is not getting filtered for me. :(

I am new to this tech, so I am confused and have no one to help me in this. This is the script I used:

for the superior1 field:

```
Sub Entering(Source As Field)
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As Notesdocument
    Dim work As  New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim workspace As  New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim sname As String
    Dim consr As String
    Dim cview As notesview

    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set uidoc = work.CurrentDocument
    Set uidocs = workspace.currentdocument  
    Set cview = db.getview("(Application)")

    'etype = uidoc.FieldGetText("Office") 
    'ftype = uidoc.FieldGetText("Group") 

    etype = "TSP"
    ftype = "TSP1-G"

    If(etype <> "" And ftype <> "")  Then
        Call filter  
    End If

    Set view = db.getview("(x_search_staff)")
    Set doc = view.GetDocumentByKey (uidoc.fieldgettext("Superior1"),True)

    If doc Is Nothing Then
        Msgbox "There is no previous transaction please select new trasaction.", 16, "Information"
        Call uidoc.FieldClear("Superior1")
        Call uidoc.gotofield ("Group")
        Call uidoc.gotofield ("Office")
        continue = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call uidoc.Refresh 
End Sub
```

from the script library ...

```
Sub filter
    Dim s As New notessession
    Dim w As New notesuiworkspace
    Dim uidoc As notesuidocument
    Dim doc As notesdocument, newdoc As notesdocument, d As notesdocument, dd As notesdocument
    Dim doc1 As NotesDocument, newdoc1 As NotesDocument
    Dim dc As notesdocumentcollection
    Dim bc As notesdocumentcollection
    Dim view As notesview, v As notesview
    Dim db As notesdatabase
    Dim nextdoc As NotesDocument
    Dim cview As notesview
    Dim cnview As NotesView
    Dim get_db As New notesdatabase(gsserver2, gspath2 & "Master\TSP_Staff.nsf")

    Set db = s.currentdatabase

    Set view = get_db.getview("(Staff Info)")
    Set cview = db.getview("(x_search_staff)")
    Set cnview = db.getview("(x_superior)")
    Set uidoc=w.CurrentDocument 

    'To delet searched previous datas from form2 ----------------------------------------
    Print "Please wait ..."

    key = "Approver2"
    Set v = db.getview("(x_delete_2)")
    Set dc = v.GetAlldocumentsByKey(key,True)
    'Set bc = v.GetAlldocumentsByKey(key,True)

    'Call bc.RemoveAll(True)
    Call dc.RemoveAll(True)
    Call cview.Refresh

    Call view.Refresh
    Call cnview.Refresh
    Call v.Refresh

    'To start searching process based on Superior1 --------------------------------------

    'f1= uidoc.FieldGetText("Office") 
    f1= uidoc.FieldGetText("Group") 
    'f1 = "TSP1-G"

    Set dc = view.getalldocumentsbykey(f1, True) 
    'Set bc = view.getalldocumentsbykey(f2, True)

    For b =1 To dc.count
        Set doc = dc.getnthdocument(b)
        Set newdoc = doc.copytodatabase(db)
        'For c =1 To bc.count
        'Set doc1 = bc.getnthdocument(b)
        'Set newdoc1 = doc.copytodatabase(db)


        If doc.form(0) = "Approver" Then
        'If doc1.form(0) = "Approver" Then
            newdoc.form = "Approver2"
            'newdoc1.form = "Approver2"
            'End If 

        End If 
        newdoc.save True, True 
         ' Next
         'newdoc.save True, True
         'Next

        Call w.viewrefresh
        Call cview.Refresh
        Call v.Refresh
        Call cnview.Refresh
        Call view.Refresh

        Print "Process Completed....."
End Sub
```

if u got another way for this requirement temme in stepwise wat to do... or else... chk out ma script for errors... hope u help me :( today due date for this task...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how smart it is to filter the documents shown in a view by deleting documents from a database :)

My suggestion is to first post the code properly. This is simply unreadable.

How to display only subset of documents in your dialog list?

Create a hidden field on your form (you'll fill it with values you want displayed in the list using your code).
And then, on your dialog list field properties, second tab, set choices option to be "Use formula for choices" and set it to be the hidden field name.

Ask if you need more help...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very hard to follow, but if I understand your intention and parts of the `filter` function (does it even compile?) you could replace all of the code with this [@dblookup](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/0/4d1d4f061d97527185256c54004bfb35?OpenDocument)-based formula in "use formula for choices" section of **superior1** properties:

```
@dblookup("":"ReCache";"ServerName":"foo\Master\TSP_Staff.nsf";"(Staff Info)";Group;NameOfInterestingField);
```

You might want to add a [@sort](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/7911d132c4b91cf085256c54004c11fc?OpenDocument) and/or [@unique](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/855dc7fcfd5fec9a85256b870069c0ab/68df997df8ab07b885256c54004c1550?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,@unique) around it if the view contain duplicate values, and you might want to add the keyword **[FAILSILENT]** if some groups should result in an empty list.

An *even simpler* method could be to configure **superior1** to [use view dialog for choices](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/855dc7fcfd5fec9a85256b870069c0ab/f8a8190e5e9f7a5d85256c54004b6fc9?OpenDocument).